# PHP: merge two multimensioanl arrays into one

Tags: php, if-statement, multidimensional-array, foreach

I try to create a multi-dimensional array (`$list`) which should look like:

```
[
  {"uri": "http://www.example.com/1", "traverseCount": "1"},
  {"uri": "http://www.example.com/2", "traverseCount": "1"},
  {"uri": "http://www.example.com/3", "traverseCount": "1"}
]
```

But, I don't know how best I can achieve this from the following data. 
The two data sources come from two `If-Else` and **try to** create an multi-dimensional array for each case. But, at the end, I would like to generate a multidimensional array which combines the two multi-dimensional array with continuous ordered keys. (So, from the above example, http://www.example.com/1 and http://www.example.com/2 comes from the outcome of the 1st `Else-If`, and http://www.example.com/3 comes from the 2nd `Else-If`). Tricky bit is that there is `foreach` inside `Else-If`.

```
// Create an empty multidimentional array to accommodate 2 datasets (2 If-Else cases) below:
$traverseCount = 1;
$list = array(
  array(),
  array()
);
//This is the first data source. Say, it returns 2 URIs when doing the foreach loop:
$match = $graph->resourcesMatching('skos:exactMatch');
if (isset($match) == true && count($match) > 0){
  $graphuris = $match[0]->all('skos:exactMatch');
  echo '<b>skos:exactMatch Links: </b><br>';
  foreach ($graphuris as $uris) {
    $counter = 0;
    $list[$counter][0] = $uris->__toString();
    $list[$counter][1] = $traverseCount;
    $counter++;
    echo '<a href="'.$uris.'" target="_blank">'.$uris.'</a><br>';
  }
}
else {
  echo '<p>No skos:exactMatch found</p>';
}
//This is the second data source, whose multidimensional array should be added to the end of the previous multidimensional array 
$match2 = $graph->resourcesMatching('rdfs:seeAlso');
if (isset($match2) == true && count($match2) > 0){
  $graphuris2 = $match2[0]->all('rdfs:seeAlso');
  echo '<b>rdfs:seeAlso Links: </b><br>';
  foreach ($graphuris2 as $uris2) {
    $counter = 0;
    $list[$counter][0] = $uris2->__toString();
    $list[$counter][1] = $traverseCount;
    $counter++;
    echo '<a href="'.$uris2.'" target="_blank">'.$uris2.'</a><br>';
  }
}
else{
  echo '<p>No rdfs:seeAlso found</p><br>';
}
// $traverseCount is always 1 until here, but it needs to add 1 for the next script to run.
$traverseCount++;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not need to be that complicated. Adding to the array can be done without any need for the `$counter` like this.

```
// Create an empty multidimentional array to accommodate 2 datasets (2 If-Else cases) below:
$traverseCount = 1;

$list = array();
//This is the first data source. Say, it returns 2 URIs when doing the foreach loop:
$match = $graph->resourcesMatching('skos:exactMatch');
if (isset($match) == true && count($match) > 0){
  $graphuris = $match[0]->all('skos:exactMatch');
  echo '<b>skos:exactMatch Links: </b><br>';
  foreach ($graphuris as $uris) {

    $list[] = array('uri'           => $uris->__toString(), 
                    'traversecount' => $traverseCount
                    );

    echo '<a href="'.$uris.'" target="_blank">'.$uris.'</a><br>';
  }
}
else {
  echo '<p>No skos:exactMatch found</p>';
}
//This is the second data source, whose multidimensional array should be added to the end of the previous multidimensional array 
$match2 = $graph->resourcesMatching('rdfs:seeAlso');
if (isset($match2) == true && count($match2) > 0){
  $graphuris2 = $match2[0]->all('rdfs:seeAlso');
  echo '<b>rdfs:seeAlso Links: </b><br>';
  foreach ($graphuris2 as $uris2) {
    $list[] = array('uri'           => $uris2->__toString(), 
                    'traversecount' => $traverseCount
                    );

    echo '<a href="'.$uris2.'" target="_blank">'.$uris2.'</a><br>';
  }
}
else{
  echo '<p>No rdfs:seeAlso found</p><br>';
}
// $traverseCount is always 1 until here, but it needs to add 1 for the next script to run.
$traverseCount++;
```

> I am a bit confused about `$traverseCount` as it does not seem to change in your code until both loops are completed.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed, it is not that complicated. Sometimes, I may think too much and get lost...`$traverseCount` is a bit confusing, as it is not directly related to the question here. Rather it would be used for the next thing I would like to implement, which would be another challenge.

Comment: Good luck with the next challenge :)

Answer (score 1):

You always reset this `$counter` to 0 in each iteration. Instead just append new element to array:

```
$list = [];

if () {
    foreach () {
        $list[] = [
            $uris->__toString(),
            $traverseCount
        ];
    }
}
```

Here I don't use counter, just adding new element to array using `$list[]` and indexes will auto-increment.

`$uris->__toString()` and `$traverseCount` automatically put to 0 and 1 indexes

---

I don't see how your `$traverseCount` changes as it's assigned 1 at the beginning and only at the end it's incremented.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is always good to know alternatives. I prefer to use an associative array, and that's the only reason to give @RiggsFolly the credit for the answer.